# Lazily evaluating an iterator of futures in rust

Tags: rust, iterator, future

I am new to rust, and it feels like there should be a function to do what I want and I just haven't found it yet.

Anyway, I've been playing with iterators and lazy evaluation because, hey, functional programming is cool.  I'm aware that I can do what I want with for loops, and hey, if that's how it has to be done I guess that's what I'll do.  But I was curious to see if there was a way I can do this in a functional style.

I have reduced what I want to a toy problem:

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9073a29ad6b6b60645ade751a1afffa4)

```
#[tokio::main]
fn main() {
    // Example without futures to show what I want
    let sync = (1..3)
      .map(|x| {println!("In map, with element {}", x); x + 1})
      .position(|x| x > 2);
    
    match sync {
        Some(x) => println!("{}", x),
        None => println!("not found"),
    }
    
    // Obviously doesn't work because position is getting an iterator of 
    // futures, not an iterator of ints.  How do I await on this future?  Note:
    // I still want this to be lazily evaluated, with the `map` function only 
    // being evaluated when necessary.  Something like join_all would evaluate
    // the map over every element, when in this case only two evaluations are
    // necessary.
    /*let asyn = (1..3)
        .map(|x| async {println!("In map, with element {}", x); x+1})
        .position(|x| x > 2);
    
    match sync {
        Some(x) => println!("{}", x),
        None => println!("not found"),
    }*/
}
```

Given in the second half of the function, my `map` generates an iterator of futures, how do I lazily `await` on them?  I don't want to parallel evaluate the entire sequence, because in this example, only the first two elements need to be evaluated before something matching the `position` is found.

I've found a lot of references to `streams`, however most of the stream stuff I've seen has to do with parallel evaluating.  What I really want to happen under the hood is for the routine to evaluate the map on one value, defer until the future is complete, continue on through the position function, before evaluating the map on the next value.

Note: This is just a toy problem, and so I am obviously generating futures trivally.  In my actual problem, the `Future` is being generated by a network request.

Comment: A stream doesn't do concurrent processing unless you tell it to via `.buffered()`, `.*_unordered()`, or `.*_concurrent()` methods.